# error invalid conversion from int to const char* [fpermissive] in C

Tags: c, sockets, client-server, webclient

I get this error when i run the following code , on line 21

Error

> error invalid conversion from int to const char*  [fpermissive]

Code

```
receive(struct sockaddr_in sockad, struct message m){
  int rc;
  int i;
  int ibuf;
  i = sizeof(sockad);
  rc = recvfrom(sd,&m,strlen(ibuf),0,(struct sockaddr *)&sockad,(unsigned long)&i ); /* line 21*/ 
  if (rc < 0) {
    perror("recvfrom"); exit(1);
  }
}
```

I tried the solutions that in stackoverflow but no luck

Comment: There are several things wrong with this fragment, but without seeing the _complete program_ we can't tell you how to fix it.  (For instance, I strongly suspect the prototype for `receive` is wrong, so I need to see the caller.)

Comment: You are passing `ibuf`, an `int`, to function `strlen()`, which expects its argument to be a `char *`, pointing to a null-terminated array of characters.  Since `ibuf` is not even initialized, that cannot be what you actually want to do.

Comment: Also: `int i;` --> `socklen_t i;`

Comment: In order to avoid a lot of guessing, please provide more code. Need code which calls `receive()`..  ALso need code for the function `recvfrom()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is caused by `strlen(ibuf)`... when `int ibuf`...

You should pass a string to `strlen`, although you might have intended to use `sizeof(m)`.

You might have also intended to use pointers, as in `struct message *m`, so that:

```
void receive(struct sockaddr_in * sockad, struct message * m){
  int rc;
  socklen_t i;
  i = sizeof(*sockad);
  rc = recvfrom(sd, m, sizeof(*m),0, sockad, &i ); /* line 21*/ 
  if (rc < 0) {
    perror("recvfrom"); exit(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: so what should i have to do?

Comment: `(unsigned long)&i` with `i` an uninitialized `int` is also wrong, and the `struct sockaddr_in` argument also probably wants to be a pointer to a variable in the caller.

Comment: @MariyamMohammedJalil, I'm not sure what your initial intention was, but I updated the answer with more details.

Comment: @zwol - Yeah, I just noticed, nice catch.

Comment: @Myst One more thing, `socklen_t` is not the same thing as `unsigned long` - the whole point of its being different from `size_t` is that it needs to _not_ be `unsigned long` on 64-bit ABIs, for reasons which will not fit in this comment box.

Comment: ... and I suppose this ignores the possibility of a short message, but I don't actually know how to handle short UDP messages myself, so :shrug:

Comment: @zwol - Thanks :) I love answering here because I learn new things every time I'm exposed to other people approaches. I would probably avoid this sort of specialized encapsulation (as well as the `exit` on error), but I don't have much experience with UDP.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the code:

strlen(ibuf)

ibuf is an integer, not string.

Comment: so what should i have to do?